# How to do something like "onErrorFlatMap" and stay in "error rail" in Spring reactive?

Tags: spring, project-reactor

Let's say a Flux or Mono produces an error and I want to perform a non-blocking side-effect, for example sending an email, when this error occurs. What I'd like to achieve is something like this:

```
val myMono = ..
myMono.onErrorFlatMap { throwable ->
    emailService.sendEmail(...).map(throwable)
}
```

I'd like to continue on the "error rail" after the email is sent, i.e. not recover using something like `onErrorResume(..)`. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`onErrorResume` is still the preferred way to go:

```
mono.onErrorResume(e -> emailService.sendEmail(...)
                                    .then(Mono.error(e))
);
```